# load XML into HTML with jQuery (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I try to load a XML database in a web page using jQuery (like say in subject).

My database looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <villes>

 <ville>
  <idville>14</idville>
  <nomville>Arles</nomville>
  <site>http://www.pays-arles.org/e-patrimoine/communes/arles/</site>
  <patrimoine>
    <fiche>http://www.pays-arles.org/e-patrimoine/communes/arles/article/abbaye-de-montmajour</fiche>
    <identifiant>445</identifiant>
    <titre>Abbaye de Montmajour</titre>
    <description>blabla</description>
    <latitude>43.705856</latitude>
    <longitude>4.664383</longitude>
    <MOTS>
      <themes>Religion</themes>
      <categoriedelarchitecture>Architecture religieuse, funéraire et commémorative</categoriedelarchitecture>
      <typedarchitecture>Architecture religieuse</typedarchitecture>
      <appartenance>Monument historique classé</appartenance>
      <epoque>Moyen-Age</epoque>
      <stylearchitectural>Roman provençal</stylearchitectural>
      <datation>XIIe siècle</datation>
      <edifice>Bâtiment religieux</edifice>
      <propriete>Etat</propriete>
    </MOTS>
    <images>
      <image>http://www.pays-arles.org/e-patrimoine/IMG/jpg/montmajour.jpg</image>
      <image>http://www.pays-arles.org/e-patrimoine/IMG/jpg/montmajour-4.jpg</image>
      <image>http://www.pays-arles.org/e-patrimoine/IMG/jpg/montmajour-5.jpg</image>
      <image>http://www.pays-arles.org/e-patrimoine/IMG/jpg/montmajour-6.jpg</image>
    </images>
    </patrimoine>

    <patrimoine>
      ...
    </patrimoine>

    <patrimoine>
      ...
    </patrimoine>
  </ville>

  <ville>
    ...
  </villes>

  <ville>
    ...
  </villes>

</villes>
```

This is just a sample of my database...
And here is my HTML:

```
<!DocType html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content_type" content=text/html; charset="utf-8" />
     <title>spip.php.xml - database</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#.css" media="all" />
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

     <header>

     </header>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
            {   
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "spip.php.xml",
                    dataType:"xml",
                    success:function(xml)
                    {
                        $(xml).find('ville').each(
                        function()
                        { 
                            var idville = $(this).find('idville');
                            var nomville= $(this).find('nomville').text();
                            var site= $(this).find('site').text();
                            $('<div class="items" id="'+idville+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+site+'">'+nomville+'</a>').appendTo('#Div_XML');
                            $(this).find('patrimoine').each(
                                function()
                                {
                                    var fiche = $(this).find('fiche').text();
                                    var identifiant = $(this).find('identifiant').text();
                                    var titre = $(this).find('titre').text();
                                    var description = $(this).find('description').text();
                                    var latitude = $(this).find('latitude').text();
                                    $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="#">MOTS</a>').appendTo('Div_XML');
                                    $(this).find('MOTS').each(
                                        function()
                                        {
                                            var themes = $(this).find('themes').text();
                                            var categoriedelarchitecture = $(this).find('categoriedelarchitecture').text();
                                            var typedarchitecture = $(this).find('typedarchitecture').text();
                                            var appartenance = $(this).find('appartenance').text();
                                            var epoque = $(this).find('epoque').text();
                                            var stylearchitectural = $(this).find('stylearchitectural').text();
                                            var datation = $(this).find('datation').text();
                                            var edifice = $(this).find('edifice').text();
                                            var propriete = $(this).find('propriete').text();
                                            $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="#">MOTS</a>').appendTo('Div_XML');
                                        }); 
                                    $(this).find('images').each(
                                        function()
                                        {
                                            var image = $(this).find('image').text();
                                            $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="#">MOTS</a>').appendTo('Div_XML');
                                        });
                                });
                        });
                    });
            });
     </script>
     <footer>

     </footer>

 </body>
```

I just followed  [this tutorial](http://pckult.developpez.com/tutoriels/javascript/frameworks/jquery/lecture-fichier-xml/)

Obvious, that don't work, why?

And how can I create a condition to get only "Arles" city?

Comment: Dumping a bunch of code along with ...`that don't work, why` is not a proper problem statement. What doesn't work?

Comment: I mean my html doesn't display my database, just a white page.

Comment: so start in browser console and provide debugging information from there. Any errors thrown? Is request being made in network tab? Is expected data being returned in request? There are lots of parts of an ajax request that can go wrong, you need to isolate them

Comment: there is errors, but I don't know what's the solution.

Comment: well what are the errors?

Comment: just "}" missed line 62.. but  all "{}" are at there good place for me